# How to setup a Magento rewrite rule that keeps it's GET parameters

Tags: magento

In our Magento shop we need a few rewrite rules that redirect to another domain. I know how to do that in the Magento Backend Rewrite URl Module, but cannot find a way to let the redirect keep it's parameters.

Is there anyway to do this in Magento, or must this be done with Apache mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

If you're implementing the redirect in apache (which is what it looks like?), you'll need to write the apache rule to keep the request parameters.

Comment: No, I know how to do that with Apache mod_rewrite, but prefer to do from the Magento backend (clarified my question).