# Magento URL Rewrite Management preserve GET parameters

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

I am using to use the Magneto's URL Rewrite Management to redirect a bunch of pages.
However, the URLs come in with affiliate information i.e. `www.mysite.com/?aff=123`
when Magneto redirects to the correct page it losses the aff=123.

How can i preserve this information?

Comment: Somewhat like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158554/how-to-setup-a-magento-rewrite-rule-that-keeps-its-get-parameters

Comment: How are you doing your redirects? Can you please post the code that forms redirect URL and actually does the redirecting?

Comment: I don't have code i am using magento's URL Rewrite Management

Comment: in admin Catalog->URL Rewrite Management

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no way to do that inside Magento.
You will need to do this on Apache mod_rewrite editing .htaccess file and put **[QSA]** (Query String Append) at the end of the redirect line.

For example:

```
RewriteRule somedir/(.*) somedir2/$1 [QSA]
```

It would redirect

www.mysite.com/somedir/hello.php?test=1

to

www.mysite.com/somedir2/hello.php?test=1

Comment: i found a way to put it into
/branches/magento-cms/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Url/Rewrite.php
by getting the params, then appending it to the $targetUrl

Comment: Yeap, certainly this is a way for doing that. So let me add "there is no way to do that inside Magento without compromising the core source on later updates". ;-)