# How Can I edit magento Rewrite.php to keep get parameters

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

I have the same issue described here: [Magento URL Rewrite Management preserve GET parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783424/magento-url-rewrite-management-preserve-get-parameters)

Which kind of changes should I do to Rewrite.php?  Is there any other way to make it work in general without changing rewrite.php?

Comment: Please see also my answer about [Magento category redirect cuts off the querystring of an url][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629722/magento-category-redirect-cuts-off-the-querystring-of-an-url

Answer (score 1):

Build the urls like:

```
$this->getUrl("*/controller/action", array('param1'=>value, '_current'=>true));
```

The value `'_current'=>true` will keep your current params in the new URL