# Magento product redirect remove the querystring from an url

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, redirect, query-string

For my Magento 1.9.1 project, I want to implement affiliate tracking. For affiliate tracking I will add a  querystring to Magento URL. It's Working good for all the URL except product URL. Whenever I hit the product URL it will redirect to the original string and lost the querystring.

```
 Affiliate URL –> https://www.myshop.com/abc-product.html?aff=3
 Redirect to original URL –> https://www.myshop.com/abc-product.html
```

I have tried with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29433181/1969866) also but its not working for me.

I have also tried [this](https://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/Magento-Redirect-Loses-URL-Querystring/m-p/4773) but no success.

And it is happening only with product URL, other URLs are not redirected.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 1 does not behave like this. Most likely you are having an Issue with your .htaccess file (or some custom Module). Share your htaccess contents and a list of installed modules.